# How can i have a vertical graph instead of horizontal?

Tags: python, graph

my code is:

```
df_superhost = df.groupby(['host_is_superhost'])[['price']].mean().plot(kind='barh')
```

df_superhost.set(xlabel='prix_moyen', ylabel="superhost", title="Variabilité des prix si le owner est un superhost")
df_superhost

and my graph is: [image]

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if the 'h' in `kind='barh'` means horizontal?

Comment: oh ok it works i remove the H to have kind='bar' and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking for the horizontal plot with

```
plot(kind='barh')
```

try

```
plot(kind='bar')
```

to get the default vertical kind.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "h" from have:

```
kind=bar
```